# Fastest way to check occurrence of a set of substrings in a large collection of documents using R

Tags: r, string, performance, substring, stringi

I have a large collection of documents, `dc`, (with several million rows) with the following `data.frame` structure

```
doc_id    body
  1       'sdfadfs...'
  2       'dfadf...'
  3       'sadf....'
```

I also have about 10,000 terms (or substrings) stored in `terms` (`terms=c('sfa','adfa','dfad',...)`).

I want to find the occurrence of each term for each document of `dc`. In the end, I want the result to be something like this

```
doc_id term
  1    'sfa'
  1    'dfad'
  2    'adfa'
  3    'sfa'
  3    'dfad'
```

Currently, I'm using the following code (with the help of `stri_detect_fixed`)

```
res_all=lapply(terms,function(term_i){ #loop over each term
    res=stri_detect_fixed(dc$body,term_i) #check occurrence of one term in each document
    
    data.frame(doc_id=which(res),term=term_i)
   
  })
  
bind_rows(res_all)
```

However, the above code is quite slow. Is there anything I can do to speed up the code?

Comment: For a given document, do you just want to know _if_ a term occurs? Or do you want to know _how many times_ a term occurs?

Comment: @MikaelJagan just 'if'

Comment: Have you tried parallelizing the loop (e.g., replacing `lapply` with `parallel::mclapply`)? Or thinking about optimizations based on nesting of terms? If a string doesn't have `"a"` as a substring, then it can't have `"ab"` as a substring, etc.

Comment: FWIW, creating a list of several thousand data frames is quite inefficient. It would be better to have your function return just `which(res)`. Then you could construct your data frame efficiently as `data.frame(doc_id = unlist(res_all, FALSE, FALSE), term = rep.int(gl(length(terms), 1L, labels = terms), lengths(res_all, FALSE)))`.

Comment: Looks like the bottleneck for this task could be in the data I/O of reading millions of rows for many documents rather than the matching itself. Perhaps worth considering shooting the `awk` folks a question?

Comment: Without proper MRE, it is hard to know which method is fastest. Given that your data is supposed to be quite substantial, it might be that the bottleneck is not the processing time itself, but the I/O, as @DonaldSeinen suggests. Please provide MRE that capture your problem. Only then we can try to do optimization.

Comment: @MikaelJagan Thanks! I tried parallelizing, however, because I have quite a few document collections, the memory usage is a problem. Also, all terms are unique, therefore nesting does not help much.

Comment: @DonaldSeinen Thanks. I never heard of `awk`. Will check it

Answer (score 0):

Collapse the `term` values in one pattern and use it in `stringr::str_extract_all` which will return a list. Use `unnest` to get each term as separate row.

```
library(dplyr)

terms=c('sfa','adfa','dfad', ...)
pat <- sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', paste0(terms, collapse = '|'))

df %>%
  mutate(term = stringr::str_extract_all(body, pat)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(term)
```

Word boundaries (`\\b`) are added to the pattern so that `'sfa'` does not match with terms like `'asfa'` or `'sfad'` etc.